# Is a URL with multiple consecutive dots valid

Tags: url, jquery-validate

I use [jquery validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) for url & it return true for this url:

`http://www.abc...com`

I'm not sure if it is a valid url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes A url with many dots is valid. However a domain name with multiple consecutive dots is not valid since the length of each label has to be more than 0.

See:
 https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2011-January/082725.html

To be conversant with URL semantics, you would need to read:

[Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

In short there could be as many dots in the domain name section. However there should be at least a label of 1 to 63 characters between these dots. Refer to:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax

Comment: how is component separated if there are many dots (in case of my example)

Comment: A.b.c.d is a valid domain name. Here A, b, c, d are all labels that I referred to as components. For eg. Mail.yahoo.com is valid. The rightmost label is the top level domain ".com". Note I am assuming that the confusion is about the multiple dots in the domain name section of the URL

Comment: Ahh. I understand your question. This is not valid since the length of a label should be between 1 and 63. https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2011-January/082725.html

Comment: so basically, an url contains 2 dots (..) is not valid because the label is empty?

Comment: Yes. The example in the question is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is valid.

See this description of allowed characters in Unreserved Section:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3

```
2.3. Unreserved Characters

Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```